# Request not reaching server (Host header injection)

Tags: laravel, http-headers, burp

I have a project in which the client's requirement is to guard against the host header injection attack. I handled the problem at the application level, creating a middleware that checks for the incoming "Host" header and then aborts (403) if it's not among the trusted ones. The problem is how to test this code, as I don't know about security testing much. I learned that there's the Burp Suite proxy tool to intercept any request and edit the headers so I did that. However, I'm getting a very strange behavior: when I edit the host header, the request doesn't even hit my server.

Allow me to explain the scenario. I'm on the password reset page, i.e., GET `/lender/password/reset`. On this page we have to enter the email address and hit the reset button, which sends a POST to `/lender/password/email` and redirects back to GET `/lender/password/reset` (Laravel devs will recognize this standard, baked-in flow).

[image]

So, when I use Burp tools and don't tamper with the headers, the app works as expected, but when I change the "Host" (say, to google.com), then the above-mentioned POST request gets converted to a GET request and since the host is now new, it doesn't even reach the application.

Please see this screenshot from the Burp tools history below (the free edition doesn't allow an export but I'll type it out if needed). Looks at lines 468 and 469: the POST to `/lender/password/email` is getting converted to a GET, and then naturally there's a 404 on google.com. It's also strange that there's a 301 redirect on line 468 (showing the app's hostname) which isn't part of the normal flow.

[image]

My problem is that the client is using this to claim that our application isn't safe against this attack, whereas to me it looks like the tampered requests aren't even reaching our server and there's this weird 301. The ideal outcome would be to send the user back when a wrong "Host" value is received.

And finally, what would be the right way to conduct this attack?

Comment: Different hosts will likely not be sent to your laravel application by your webserver so I think the correct place to look is your webserver's default listener.

Comment: @apokryfos Good point. I was the thinking the same. Maybe the 301 is issued by the webserver. I'll explore again and comment here soon.